# C# - Execute a javascript __DoPostBack function to execute actions in a website

Tags: javascript, c#, web, postback, dopostback

I'm writing a C# program that need to download a file from a website. The link is the following: http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Implant

My target is the export all the table when I click a button in my Windows Form, so for first I would like to execute the (All) voice that executes the `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DG1$ctl20$ctl05','')`, then I would like to execute the "Export to CSV" voice that executes `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl03','')` and this last call download the CSV file.

I'm a newbie in implementing javascript function on C# programs. Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a note: The mentioned javascript function call starts a HTTP post request to an ASP.NET site. The string `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DG1$ctl20$ctl05` indicates that the site uses generated element ids to identify html elements on the server side. Any change to the page structure can change this identifier so probably its hard to find that function call again after page layout changes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a desktop application and would like to download data from an Asp.Net page.  You can conquer this several different ways:  `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, and etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If we suppose that the layout of the page will never change? For me it's not a problem now

Comment: Hi Greg, you're right. But I read on internet that with WebClient I can't use javascript functions

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript, you can use the `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse and manipulate the page?  I'm assuming you would be using JavaScript to manipulate the page?

Comment: @D3m Just another note: you can try to issue the http request directly, as long as you include all relevant form fields from the source page, including the fields `_VIEWSTATE' and `_EVENTVALIDATION`. You can use the developer tools from chrome for example to capture the sent request.